# Is it possible to send packets using spoofed public IP?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, spoofing

**Is it possible to send a web packet using a spoofed public IP** (Custom source IP header) to a server (Raspberry Pi), and have the Pi log the packet. **The response is not important**, nor is the method used(TCP, UDP, HTTP), **only the initial one way communication**.

I have searched around on the first and second pages of google, but **all examples I could find demonstrate this on local a IP such as 10.0.2.12. Will these examples work if I use a destination such as 67.70.XX.XX?**

I'm a newbie to python networking, any help at all, or links to other resources is greatly appreciated.

**Thanks everyone for your time! :)**

Comment: There is the scapy Python package. It is a poweful tool which might be difficult to master for a newbie. https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much harder to spoof your public IP that it seems. You'll need to replace your ISP-box with your own modem..

@Number File's answer is pretty wrong. It's easy to spoof an IP on the local network (basically the `src` field of IP) but much harder on a public level.

Have a look at https://superuser.com/a/619483

Comment: I looked into that thread a bit, yeah using NMAP I was only able to achieve the results I was looking for on my local network , and not on the main internet. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do so with tools such as nmap, though the packets will go to the IP you spoof, not yours. For this reason, doing so is generally pointless unless you’re trying to make an ISP or website look bad. Note: nmap is not a python program, in order to use it in python, you need to call it with something like os.system(“nmap” + args)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What would the args look like? I have only ever used nmap for network scanning and not the sending of packets. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Type -S Ip for the spoof